# A regular $n$-gon contains a regular $m$-gon, with $n,m$ coprime, no sides coinciding. What is the maximum number of contact points between them?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polygons

A regular $n$-gon contains a regular $m$-gon, where $n$ and $m$ are coprime, with no sides coinciding.

> What is the maximum number of contact points between the $n$-gon and the $m$-gon?

(I'm not asking for the maximum in terms of $n$ and $m$; I'm asking for the absolute maximum.)

I made up this question. My guess is that the maximum is four, and that when this maximum is attained the polygons share a line of symmetry. (I made a simple [example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pg742fd2qa) showing that four is attainable.)

I made a [desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xvzoubcysu) of a regular $6$-gon containing a regular $7$-gon. You can use the sliders to expand/rotate/translate them.

I posted a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4700808/398708) on MSE.

Comment: Sliding to $R=1{.}13$, $T=-0{.}27$, $p=-0{.}035$, $q=-0{.}003$, it looks like there are 5-ish contact points. I haven’t tried to verify this other than by eyeballing.